# Matching specific regex words in url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I must admit I've never gotten used to using regex, however recently I ran into a problem where the work around would've been more of a pain than using regex. I need to be able to match anything that follows the following pattern at the beginning of a string:
`{any_url_safe_word}` +( `"/http://"`  || `"/https://"` || `"www."`) + `{any word}`.
So the following should match:

- `cars/http://google.com#test`
- `cars/https://google.com#test`
- `cars/www.google.com#test`

The follwing shouldn't match:

- `cars/httdp://google.com#test`
- `cars/http:/google.com#test`

What I tried so far is: `^[\w]{1,500}\/[(http\:\/\/)|(https:\/\/])|([www\.])]{0,50}`, but that matches `cars/http` from `cars/httpd://google.com`.

Comment: What is this: {any_url_safe_word}?

Comment: e.g: cars, ca_rs, ca_1_rs, etc. Not "c a r s".

Answer (score 3):

This regex could do:

```
^[\w\d]+\/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
```

And if you want to get everything that comes after it, you can just add `(.*)` to the end...

[`Live DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/hB9gR4)

[image]

And since it seems that the more or less general list of URL safe words contains `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=` [`Source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/1519058), you may include that too, so you'll get (after simplification):

```
^[!#$&-.0-;=?-\[\]_a-z~]+\/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
```

Comment: Not quite that simple : a good regexp, just for domain name pattern matching, from http://hexillion.com/samples/ would be `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?$`

Comment: True, matching a domain pattern is much complex, I just picked the simplest version wich fits his needs (I hope so)

Comment: Heh - yeah, drop the `\w\d ... ` for your permitted list of characters in a `[ ... ]` and you should be good I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$words = array(
    'cars/http://google.com#test',
    'cars/https://google.com#test',
    'cars/www.google.com#test',
    'cars/httdp://google.com#test',
    'cars/http:/google.com#test',
    'c a r s/http:/google.com#test'
    );

foreach($words as $value)
{
    /*
      \S+           - at least one non-space symbol
      \/            - slash
      (https?:\/\/) - http with possible s then ://
      |             - or
      (www\.)       - www.
      .+            - at least one symbol
     */
    if (preg_match('/^\S+\/(https?:\/\/)|(www\.).+/', $value))
    {
        print $value. " good\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print $value. " bad\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
cars/http://google.com#test good
cars/https://google.com#test good
cars/www.google.com#test good
cars/httdp://google.com#test bad
cars/http:/google.com#test bad
c a r s/http:/google.com#test bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Ba-z0-9-_.~%5D%2a%2F%28https%3F%3A%2F%2F%7Cwww%5C.%29%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%5C.%5Ba-z%5D%7B2%2C6%7D%28%5B%2F%5C%3F%23a-z0-9-_.~%5D%29%2a&input=cars%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%23test%0Acars%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%23test%0Acars%2Fwww.google.com%23test%0A%0Acars%2Fhttdp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%23test%0Acars%2Fhttp%3A%2Fgoogle.com%23test).

`[a-z0-9-_.~]+/(https?://|www\.)[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,6}([/?#a-z0-9-_.~])*`

Edit: taken @CD001 comment into account. Be sure to use the `i` modifier if you don't mind case-sensitivity.

Comment: The problem with using `\w` is that it matches any Perl "word" character and that changes depending on the locale in which PHP is running - technically you'll be matching characters like `Ö` which are **not** valid URL chars (yet).